# AES encryption in java / decrypt in C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography

I'm using the below code to encrypt an email address using my own key in java:

```
byte[] key = "testKeyMaster123".getBytes("UTF-8");
SecretKeySpec _secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
String input = "some.email.m@gmail.com";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
byte[] bytes = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _secretKey);
byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
result = Base64.encodeToString(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and the result is:

```
9�Ѹ��m�G���M�`7<z��je�G�L
```

and the encoded result is:

```
i8PWV9EV5N5L0F5w/pZarRc7G8hJIaC8v/lefv0VaeQ=
```

and in c# I'm using the below code to decrypt it:

```
var text = "i8PWV9EV5N5L0F5w/pZarRc7G8hJIaC8v/lefv0VaeQ=";
text = Util.decodeBase64(text);
RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 128;
rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 128;
byte[] encryptedData = HexToBytes(text);

byte[] pwdBytes = key;
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
int len = pwdBytes.Length;
if (len > keyBytes.Length)
{
    len = keyBytes.Length;
}
Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
byte[] plainText = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
```

but the decoded result is:

```
���W���K�^p��Z�;�I!����^~�i�
```

which looks different than the java and decrypted  result is not the email, it's become this:

```
,���M d�������
```

I'm a newbie in a field of encryption/decryption, and most of the above code is gathered from here and there. I understood some of the code as I went through it but I don't know what's wrong here. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Best is not to pick code from here and there, but try to understand exactly what it does. Read the documentation, read some information about the AES encryption, what modes it takes, key lengths, paddings, IVs. Check if the defaults in Java match those in C++.

Comment: Which IV does Java use? Are you sure it uses the key as the IV? I doubt that.

Comment: For AES encryption, to ensure you can decrypt the message back correctly you need to correctly specify **encryption key**, **IV vector**, and also **block cipher mode**, regardless which library or language you use. Make sure all these 3 key factors make no different.

Comment: The default block cipher mode in different languages, library, may vary. So don't leave these parameters default.

Comment: To my limited knowledge, Base64 encoding in it's plain implementation will use to encode ASCII characters, unless you feed it with another set of codes, try this part without encoding and see if you get the desired results, than choose another set of encoding.

Comment: The padding mode is incorrect, but that cannot explain the differences. Java uses PKCS#7, C# is now set to use no padding at all.

Comment: @RealSkeptic what you said is completely true, I should say that I didn't hit it well with R&D since I was in rush, but can you be kind enough to give me some useful link that explains about these in an easy way? thanks

Comment: @Jens unfortunately I don't know, my knowledge is limited in this field as I mentioned, I decrypted the result in java using the same key and it worked fine, but in c# it didn't so probably I think it's the configuration that made it different

Comment: @MaartenBodewes if I'm not mistaken if I don't specify the mode and just pass the algorithm as "AES", it will ECB which I also used in c#. the keys both are the same as they are both converted to byte array with utf-8 format. might be the IV vector?

Comment: There is no IV for ECB mode. I don't see where `key` comes from in your C# code. Can you add that bit so that it's complete?

Comment: For the Java Oracle JRE, using the default provider, `"AES"` is equivalent to "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` (and PKCS#5 padding is equivaltent to PKCS#7 padding in Java). So there is a mismatch between Java and C# for the padding mode. ArtjomB is right, without the key we cannot answer. You should print out the base64 of the key and input right before encryption / decryption, and check if you see any differences.